# How does nested placeholder "{}" work in format language?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I don't quite totaly understand how nested placeholder {} in formatting language works.
str.format()

Example:

```
>>> '{{{}}}{{{}}}'.format(25, 10)
'{25}{10}'
>>> '{{}}{{}}'.format(25, 10)
'{}{}'
>>> '{{{}}}{{}}'.format(25, 10)
'{25}{}'
>>> '{{{}}}{{{}}}'.format(25, 10)
'{25}{10}'
>>> '{{{{}}}}{{{}}}'.format(25, 10)
'{{}}{25}'
>>> '{{{{{}}}}}{{{}}}'.format(25, 10)
'{{25}}{10}'
```

Can someone explain to me in steps how will be placeholder evalued?

Answer (score 0):

According to python docs https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

```
Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces {}.  
 Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is  
 copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include a brace character in the  
 literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.
```

A simpler example to understand it will be

```
>>> '{}'.format(25)
'25'
>>> '{{}}'.format(25)
'{}'
>>> '{{{}}}'.format(25)
'{25}'
>>> '{{{{}}}}'.format(25)
'{{}}'
>>> '{{{{{}}}}}'.format(25)
'{{25}}'
>>> '{{{{{{}}}}}}'.format(25)
'{{{}}}'
```

Whenever you see a even number `(n)` of curly brace, the braces are escaped and numbers are not printed and we get `n/2` braces, but in odd number `(n)` of curly braces, the number is printed around `(n-1)/2` curly braces (based on observation)

Similar idea can be seen in the example above